# Regular Expression always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have following regular expression in JQuery. It always returns true.

```
var reg = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+");
var key = $('#keyId').val().trim();
if (key.match(reg)) {
  $("#TitleError").hide();
}
else {
  $("#TitleError").text("special characters not allowed!!").show();

}
```

It returns true for everything, for example "ABCD, ^&&&^&" should be false, it returns true.

Comment: *"I have following regular expression in JQuery"* jQuery has absolutely nothing to do with regular expressions. jQuery is a library of functions. *JavaScript* is a language with, amongst other things, regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`match` returns the matches found in the string. what you really want is `test` eg. like this

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+$/.test(key)
or 
reg.test(key)
```

Comment: Thanks Shyam. Is there any scenario match fails? I think it actually does the same?

Comment: The `^` and `$` are important here which mean that the whole string must match the expression. `"ABCD, ^&&&^&"` has some characters that match the regex so, they will be returned. If the input had none eg. like `"^&&&^&"` `match` will return `null` which will fail the boolean test

Answer (score 3):

You regexp should be:

`var reg = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+$');`

Comment: Thanks I missed the $!!

Comment: Also I was using Match instead of test as @shyam said :)